# How to add secret to crypto.createHash()?

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptography

I'm trying to create a hash using the [Node.js Crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) like this:

```TypeScript
import crypto from 'crypto';
const stringToHash = 'blah blah blah';
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256', 'mysecret123').update(stringToHash);
```

But I get a TypeScript error saying this:

> Type '"mysecret123"' has no properties in common with type
> 'HashOptions' .ts(2559)

My code conforms to the documentation examples (I think) so why is TypeScript complaining?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the meaning of [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: `Hash` does not use a key, you may be confusing [`Hash`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-hash) with [`Hmac`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-hmac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @Topaco, I was confusing [Hash](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-hash) with [Hmac](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#class-hmac).

I was using `createHash` when I should have been using `createHmac`.

This is the new working code:

```TypeScript
import crypto from 'crypto';
const stringToHash = 'blah blah blah';
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'mysecret123').update(stringToHash);
```